# Polygon feature class is not visible after creation

Tags: polygon, arcgis

I have created, deleted, and recreated this polygon feature class many time and can not figure out how to get it to show up on my map. I can see the shape in the attributes table but it will not fill in or show up unless it is selected.  Can anyone please help me?
[image: This is what the map looks like after I have created the polygon (object 7)]

Image 1: This is what the map looks like after I have created the polygon

[image: Note here when I select the object you can see the poylgon]

Image 2: Note here when I select the object you can see the poylgon

Note: The same this happens regardless if all the objects have been created To save time I am just showing one.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be the first record in the attribute table. You have a feature for bay that is "Null" thus it probably doesn't symbolize. Also, out of curiosity, I noticed that all the other features are "Null"; did you draw them in yet?

Best,

tpdance

Comment: nothing drew.  I just went back and created shapefiles so they would draw then converted to feature class and deleted old shapefiles and it is working.  But I had not luck just creating polygons in the feature class without the shapefiles first.